# What is Happy Hour?

Tags: support, chat

What is Happy Hour on the Tavern on the meta I did check to see if I could find this, but I couldn't find anything about it.  It looked interesting so I wanted to join if I would want to.

Comment: Happy hour is quiet hour.

Comment: @Emrakul What is a quiet hour?

Comment: More technically, Happy Hour is an event which was scheduled in chat for every Friday evening-ish. Also, I was being silly, sorry. If you'd like to join, you're free to just stop by!

Comment: @Emrakul But, what is it about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a reference to [Happy Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_hour):

> Happy hour is a marketing term for a period of time in which a public venue, such as a restaurant, bar, bowling alley, stadium, or state/county fair, offers discounts on alcoholic drinks, such as beer, wine, and cocktails.

More specifically, it's a bit of a "joke event" just for fun, since the room's name is "Tavern on the Meta" - and a tavern is a type of bar, which would often serve alcoholic beverages.

Comment: @Doorknob This is more serious, yes, but he actually said that it was a "joke event". :P jk(about the :P).

Answer (score 15):

During happy hour, drinks are half-price.

Of course, the meta tavern is strictly BYOB, so you'll have to bring your own discount as well.

Cheers!

Comment: So, wait; we're only allowed to bring spirits that we got at half-price?

Comment: I predict I'll be slightly more happy during the hour then...